# When do I use そう vs そうな?

Tags: grammar

In the sentence このロープは丈夫＿＿見えました。(This rope looked durable)
Do I put 丈夫**そうな**見えました。or 丈夫**そう**見えました。
I'm not quite sure how to differentiate between そう and そうな. Does そうな only work directly before nouns?

ありがとうございます！

Comment: It should be そうに by the way. The linked post explains this, but そうな creates an adj while そうに creates an adverb

Comment: @Shurim Thanks!